# How to connect to Oracle through LDAP with Ruby on Rails 5.4.2?

Tags: oracle, rails, ldap

My application is running on Rails 5.4.2/Ruby 2.7 and relies on an Oracle 19c.

I used to query an Oracle database through a classical OCI connection configuration:

**config/database.yml**

```
development:
 adapter: oci
 host: xe
 username: dqm
 password: dqm_password
```

But the organisation's IT architecture has changed, so that connections should now go through LDAP for security reasons. The URL looks like this :

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://intranet.oid-01.dama.ch:3063/EDWHPD,cn=OracleContext,dc=emea,dc=dama,dc=ch
```

I don't know how to handle this with Rails, and it raises several questions for me:

- How to describe this connection in the **database.yml** file?
- Should I use the Net-LDAP gem, and what would it bring to help establishing the connection to Oracle database?
- Do you know a tutorial explaining how to setup this type of database access?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You shouldn't store passwords in Plain Text. I recommend you look into using an Oracle Wallet as a quick fix of this security hole. I'd have to read up to see if XE supports LDAP  Authentication

Comment: Of course, I use Rails crentials to store password and URLs. In production, we don't use Oracle XE, but Oracle 19c. I could switch to Oracle 19c also for development if required...

Comment: 19c is a version. XE is an Edition. SE2 (Standard Edition), EE (Enterprise Edition), PE (Personal Edition), and XE (express Edition). Each Oracle DB has a version (19c,21c,etc) and an Edition (EE,SE2,XE) Each Edition has internal limits (eg can't Partition in SE2, can't run RAC in XE). I'm not sure if XE has the necessary components to Authenticate users against LDAP (including Active Directory)

Comment: Ah OK, sorry for the misunderstanding. We have Oracle 19c EE for our validation and production environments. And I ordered an instance for Dev too to make sure all features are available identically. Can we make such a connection through LDAP with Ruby?